# Why use dummy variables in GBM using CARET library in R

Tags: r, cart, caret, boosting

I have seen a few examples implemting the gbm algorithm on youtube using the titanic dataset. These examples have turned some factor variables into dummy/indicator variables when GBM can handle factor variables by internally creating dummies. I am working on an example with healthcare data and I have ended up transforming some factor variables with less than 10 levels into dummy variables. I want to ask if such a transformation can create a problem when it comes to classification accuracy?

My other questions are:

1. What is the benefit of using a dummy variable with gbm compared to using a factor variable with less than 10 levels?
2. Does anyone has any literature recommending or presenting a contrast to the use of dummy variables with GBM?

I will appreciate help in this regard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My experience across a bunch of data sets (some of which are documented in section 14.7 of [APM](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com)) is that it doesn't change performance in any one direction (i.e. in some changes it is betters, worse in others). I have yet to see a huge difference.

However, most tree based models have an algorithm that, when given a categorical predictor, find the optimal binary split. A lot of these look at different configurations of how to split the category (e.g. 2 values on one side, 3 on the other). If you have dummy variables, it only considers one value of that predictor at a time. Even though it has more predictors to sift through, I find that using dummy variables makes the training time shorter and the trees slightly deeper.

Max